# Comparison of user account created date + 6 months to current date: how?

Tags: drupal, drupal-rules

Im trying to create comparison of user account created date + 6 months and see if its greater than site current date and if it is to block user. (6 month expiration for user accounts)

How can I write rules comparison with numeric compare greater than withing drupal rules? Token is installed.

Comment: Is this for a single user or are you looking for this rule to batch block users?  When do you want this rule to run?